# MySQL Update if row exists, otherwise insert

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO GameScoreTotal (
    `GameName`
    , `OverallScore`
    , `GraphicsScore`
    , `StoryScore`
    , `GameplayScore`
    , `TimeScore`
    )
VALUES (
    'HomeFront'
    , '1'
    , '1'
    , '1'
    , '1'
    , '5'
    )
WHERE GameName = 'HomeFront'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY

UPDATE OverallScoreTotal = OverallScoreTotal + '1'
    , GraphicsTotal = GraphicsTotal + '1'
    , StoryTotal = StoryTotal + '1'
    , GameplayTotal = GameplayTotal + '1'
    , TimeTotal = TimeTotal + '1'
    , RatingCount = RatingCount + 1;
```

I am trying to update GameScoreTotal If we have something there otherwise insert. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- you need to define key on `GameName` name, (*a unique or primary key should do*)
- remove `WHERE` clause from the insert statement

query,

```
INSERT INTO GameScoreTotal ( `GameName` , `OverallScore` , `GraphicsScore`
                           , `StoryScore` , `GameplayScore`  , `TimeScore` )
VALUES ( 'HomeFront' , 1  , 1 , 1 , 1 , 5 )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE OverallScoreTotal = OverallScoreTotal + 1
     , GraphicsTotal = GraphicsTotal + 1
     , StoryTotal = StoryTotal + 1
     , GameplayTotal = GameplayTotal + 1
     , TimeTotal = TimeTotal + 1
     , RatingCount = RatingCount + 1;
```

SOURCE

- [**INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`.